# Problems with Disk Utility created RAID 1

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, disk-utility, usb

I have two external Seagate 5TB disk drives that are powered over the USB connection to my 2017 iMac. They are both partitioned the same:

- volume "Time Machine 1" for my iMac
- volume "Time Machine 2" for a MacBook Pro
- volume for SuperDuper copy of iMac (this is a spare volume on the second hard drive as SuperDuper is not used for the MBP
- volume "Backup"

Both iMac and MBP are set to use the two Time Machine volumes. The two Backup volumes are added to a RAID 1, so it appears as a single volume. There is just under 1TB of data on this Backup volume.

This arrangement has worked perfectly for three months. Prior to that I had a single Seagate external drive for about 5 years. Unfortunately, after temporarily connecting the Time Machine volume for the iMac to a virtual machine running on the iMac, I have been running into a strange set of problems.

1. An issue that could be a root cause of some of the problems, but also possibly not related: over the last couple of weeks, various of my USB external drives disconnect spontaneously, usually overnight when the machine is idle. This started happening with a USB thumb drive, not the Seagate drives. Of course when this happens you see the "disk not properly ejected notice". For several weeks this has only been happening with the thumb drive.
2. The "disconnect without eject" has started happening to the Seagate drives. However, this has been happening overnight while a multiple-hour copy is running.
3. I had to disconnect the Seagate drives to try to get the drives to connect to a virtual machine. For each such attempt, all volumes are unmounted, and the USB cable is pulled (from which the drive gets its power, as mentioned above). Without fail, this causes a panic, with the error message in the center of the screen in 5 languages. I have seen this occur at least 10 times now. I suspect this panic might have also corrupted the RAID, and is the source of the issues described here.
4. At this point, using Disk Utility to check on the raid now shows either "failed" on some slices, or "Rebuilding 0.0%", which can stay at 0.0% for many hours. Which slice is shown as failed and which as rebuilding seems to vary. Because the "failed" slice later appears "online" and data is present, I am suspicious of this raid-handling mechanism of Disk Utility.
5. I purchased a third identical Seagate drive because initially I thought the "failed" just meant that the drive has gone bad and I was going to just swap in the new drive. I attempted to "Repair", which provides only the process of swapping in a new slice, but not the normal fsck_hfs that is part of First Aid. However, I cannot get this to work. What rather happens is that seemingly randomly, any of the now three slices are shown as either "failed" or "rebuilding 0.0%" that hangs at that point. Please note, that sometimes "0.0%" is "0.2%", or some other small number. That is, it is not consistent to a particular slice. Sometime all the slices say "failed".
6. AppleCare gave some suggestions, but ultimately saying that this indicates a hardware problem with the USB ports, and indicates a system board replacement might be needed.
7. I moved the two Seagate drives to a spare 2012 iMac to see if these strange behaviors would persist, so as to indicate whether the problem source was the Mac or the drives. Interestingly, the "unmount and pull cable" also causes the panic! I am thinking that it is unlikely that both machines have defective system boards at this point.
8. I booted the 2012 iMac into safe mode--at this point, the two USB hard drives can be freely disconnected and reconnected without causing the panic.
9. I booted into Recovery Console to try to rebuild the drive in Disk Utility. That does not work either, again handing on "Rebuilding 0.0%" for four hours.
10. I have discovered that when Disk Utility reports the issues described, that sometimes the RAID volume cannot be mounted. However rebooting the machine will allow the RAID volume to be mounted with all of the files present.
11. I made a backup copy of the RAID partition on an available partition of the new Seagate drive. But I don't trust that that will survive, so I made a second backup copy on the spare iMac internal fusion drive.
12. Note that during these backups that run for several hours, it is typical that the drives disconnect spontaneously. This even seems to happen on the same file, which is suspicious in itself. Here is the output of rsync, which does seem to occur on a specific file:

    > WARNING: Backup/VM Archive/W10-Edge/Microsoft Edge on Windows 10.pvm/harddisk1.hdd/harddisk1.hdd.0.{5fbaabe3-6958-40ff-92a7-860e329aab41}.hds failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
    >
    > file has vanished: "/Volumes/Backup/VM Archive/W10-Edge/Microsoft Edge on Windows 10.pvm/harddisk1.hdd/harddisk1.hdd.0.{5fbaabe3-6958-40ff-92a7-860e329aab41}.hds"

    It appears that after the error message on the first line where is says "will try again", that the disk disconnected itself, because I see on the screen the warning that the disk was disconnected without unmounting, and rsync says "file has vanished". And the rsync has terminated at that point.

    So this is very odd--copying a file causes the disk to be disconnected!

    At this point, I am going to get rid of that file! But before doing so, I ran a test of copying only that file. Using Finder, the copy process hangs at about 80% complete. So it could be that the file copy is unrelated to the disconnect--it merely causes the system to wait at that point until the next spontaneous disconnect occurs. After a long time, 10 minutes or so, the following appears:

    [image: Finder error message on file copy]

    I searched on this error message and found that the problem might be resolvable using the program dot_clean. However, at this point the Backup volume is disconnected, the "did not eject message" is displayed, and a reboot is necessary to get the volume back.

    I tried the dot-clean command. It did not seem like it did anything. Rather than continue to fight this aspect, I am just going to remove the bad file and move forward.
13. For the future it appears that to avoid the panic, I must shutdown the computer before disconnection, not merely unmounting the volumes.
14. My plan at this time is that when the Backup volume is sufficiently backed up, that I will remove the RAID array, perform first aid on the affected volumes. I might decide to set them up again as RAID, or possibly revert to the earlier procedure with two normal volumes that are rsync-d by a launchd script. This would be to avoid the Disk Utility version of RAID, which seems lacking. I thought having the RAID would simplify things by avoiding this copying.

Here are my questions:

1. What is causing the panic when USB cables are disconnected, but not in Safe Mode?
2. Why does the raid rebuilding function fail?
3. Is there a way to perform the fsck_hfs on raid slices while they are part of the RAID?
4. Any recommendations on RAID vs duplicate-volumes-kept-in-sync-via-rsync?

EDIT:

Due to the problems with having the RAID 1 configuration, I decided to downgrade away from RAID and revert to the previous procedure. The old procedure is as follows:

1. Remove the RAID configuration named "Backup".
2. Create two identically sized and configured volumes on separate hard drives, named "Backup1" and "Backup2".
3. Backup1 is a copy of what used to be on Backup.
4. All procedures and functions using "Backup" modified to use Backup1.
5. Re-instate a launchd job to rsync with delete from Backup1 to Backup2, running once early morning and once middle of night.

So I effectively have a very similar functionality.

Comment: "Disconnect without eject" happens all the time.  For instance, if I plug in a USB drive that oversubscribes the available power on the USB bus, it resets and my USB drives all get ejected.  It happens and it's not a fault of macOS, your USB ports, or the drive.  But RAID 1 over USB?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Any objection to editing this down to one question? It’s not clear any one answer will overlap with the others and details relevant for one are not for the other. Especially the recommendation question

Comment: I have never regretted using Promise hardware for RAID and if I was forced to use software, paying for [soft raid](https://www.softraid.com/) has always been excellent return on investment.

Comment: I have a mini (2018) running Catalina with 2 x 10TB drives in a RAID 1.  I rebooted and had all sorts of problems.  The array rebuilt and when it was done it went back to "rebuilding: 0.0%"!  Sitting there for 6+ hours.  Very worried (I have backups, but 10TB of data will take a while to restore).

Comment: Btw, for me, it took 12+ hours to do the original rebuild.  It just so happens I was looking at Disk Utility when it finished and I thought "hey, great, I can mount it" then it went back into the rebuilding state.  :(

Comment: Decided to try to mount the partition.  That was a mistake.  Spinning ball.  So frustrating.

Comment: Forced quit Disk Util, started again... hung.  Trying to reboot, but it's hung.  I'm guessing I'm rebuilding that array.

Comment: I have the same error where the disk abruptly ejects itself and a reboot is needed. I decided to pull all files from the RAID and noticed that the error is always triggered when copying the same (50 GB) file, somewhere around 40%. So my best guess is that a sector is somehow broken, causing some sort of error internally that kicks out the disks. My rebuild also fails, so I assume  the same error happens there.